# access textview from another class

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

my text-view is in view class and i want to access it in setting class to change it's font size ... i had tried different methods but still i don't have solution :( please help me out... my code for two classes are ...

Setting class code :

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner1() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Small");
    list.add("Medium");
    list.add("Large");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());


    apply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

          if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())=="Small")
                  {
             // small1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfile1); 
              //small1.setText("raman rayat");


            //  setContentView(R.layout.view); 


              //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                //View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, null);
                //TextView myTextView = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.textfile1);

            //view1.text1.setTextSize(50);

               // myTextView.setTextSize( 5);

              //setContentView(R.layout.view);


            view1 obj =new view1();
            obj.small();

                  }
          else if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())=="Medium")
          {
            // code

          }

          else if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())=="Large")
          {
           // code

          }

          }

        });
```

view class code :

```
public class view1 extends menu {
    TextView text1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);  
        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfile1);
        Intent myintent = getIntent();
        String product = myintent.getStringExtra("product");
        text1.setText(product);
    }

    public void small() {
        text1.setText("small font");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't you need to pass data using intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SharedPreferences`. This allows you to store the font settings in your `Settings` class and load them from the `View` class.

Comment: how to use SharedPreferences ...could you please provide me some idea or edit my code according to SharedPreferences ...

Comment: @ramanrayat I suggest that you start by reading [the Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass activity instance to the class for ex using constructor. and now u can find view or can call methods of that activity class